# Exclude specific HEADERS from Response

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

how to remove headers from Response (SimpleResult)

the example of code:

```
def NoCache[A](action: Action[A]): Action[A] = Action(action.parser) { request =>
    action(request) match {
        case s: SimpleResult[_] =>
            s.withHeaders(PRAGMA -> "no-cache")
            // remove all headers with name "ETAG" HERE ??
        case result => result
    }
}
```

i did not find this functionality in documentation.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SimpleResult` and `ResponseHeader` are both case classes, you can copy them to modify the headers:

```
...
val headers = s.header.headers - ETAG + (PRAGMA -> "no-cache")
s.copy(header = s.header.copy(headers = headers))
...
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this does not work.

scala: Cannot write an instance of A to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[A]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
                s.copy(header = s.header.copy(headers = headers))
                      ^

it might work inside SimpleResult class